# Notification.requestPermission() doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification

I'm having a problem with push notifications on Chrome. On certain pcs in my network, websites normally requesting permissions to post push notifications, don't request them. That functionality works on some browsers in my network, but doesn't on others. Chrome version is  68.0.3440.106 on all the machines.
To investigate the case, I run a simple script in the console, that should trigger the browser request:

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
  if (result === 'denied') {
    console.log('denied');
    return;
  }
  if (result === 'default') {
    console.log('default');
    return;
  }
  console.log(result);
  return;
});
```

On the machines where push is working as expected, this promise resolves, whereas on the "faulty" ones, it doesn't resolve. I don't have my browser configured to either allow or deny the notifications (I've never clicked the "allow" or "deny" on the request, as it has never appeared). I don't know where to go from here, here's what I've tried so far:

- I don't have the browser notification behaviour set to either allow or deny.
- Chrome://flags shows "default" for all entries concerning push notifications.
- Console doesn't print any errors/warnings
- running chrome with --enable-logging --v=1 doesn't show anything suspicious when running the script. Here's an excerpt:

  ```
  [7772:21772:0828/101500.364:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1024)] [state:00007FFB173B67A0] PostSweep: collection_rate: 0.00067%
  [7772:21772:0828/101500.421:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1024)] [state:00007FFB173B67A0] PostSweep: collection_rate: 0%
  [7772:21772:0828/101500.422:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1430)] [state:00007FFB173B67A0] CollectGarbage: time: 15ms stack: HeapPointersOnStack marking: AtomicMarking sweeping: EagerSweeping reason: ForcedGC
  [7772:21772:0828/101500.427:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1430)] [state:00007FFB173B67A0] CollectGarbage: time: 4.9ms stack: NoHeapPointersOnStack marking: AtomicMarking sweeping: LazySweeping reason: PreciseGC
  ```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me what else to check, I'm really lost with this one. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Apparently this is some weird screen offset issue. The request shows just fine, when I have two instances of chrome running. However, when I have the request showing in one window, snapping it back to the other instance makes the request disappear. It reappears after resising the window to anything but fullscreen, or undocking the tab. Has nobody encountered this problem? This occurs among multiple machines in my workplace

Comment: `whereas on the "faulty" ones, it doesn't... ` - what exactly happens (please clarify by editing)? Its neither resolved nor rejected or it always rejects? When I was trying this, the promise always rejected - even after restarting the browser - when I once denied permission. Have you possibly denied the permission once on those browsers (assuming the promise ever rejects)?

Comment: The promise neither rejects nor resolves. I have the behaviour set to "ask", so that's not the reason unfortunately

Comment: Same issue here, but on Android Chrome. The promise is never resolved. Did you manage to fix this issue?